# dev/urandom unique ID algorithm

Tags: php

Before start, I would like to thank all and apologize because I don't speak english fluently.
Well,
I'm generating a unique number with this algorithm below.

My unique ids is not global for all products, but is used an unique id to each one, example:

News, Albums, Videos...

I don't want check in the database if this ID exists, because the traffic is too big.

**Note-1:** Exists the possibility of users submit something simultaneously.

**Note-2:** My unique ids are case sensitive.

This IDs are visible in URL, and I don't want a big ID with many chars.

**URL**

http://www.[...].com/news/a-title-of-something-post-hQ38-k8_.html

My IDs are created based in dev/urandom

```
$ID = strtr(base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(5, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)), '+=/', 'X_-');
```

Exists a best solution or this way is really good?

(Documentation) - Functions which were used in this topic:

1. **strtr** *( string $str , string $from , string $to )*
2. **base64_encode** *( string $data )*
3. **mcrypt_create_iv** ( int $size [, int $source = MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM ] )

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you are not just letting the database generate numeric IDs for you?

Comment: @Justin The databases are not equal for each product

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *not equal for each product*.

Comment: @Justin I mean I use databases that do not create unique IDs automatically

Comment: Is there any reason you are not having the DB generate the IDs though? It guarantees uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like [uniqid()](http://php.net/uniqid) does exactly what you need. You can add further obfuscation on it if needed, of course.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your approach, too. It all depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use a database to handle the ID creation for you, maybe using a UUID would do the trick. Since you mention /dev/urandom which is specific to Linux, I suppose using the Linux kernel to generate the UUID for you is not an issue. In that case you can read UUIDs from: `/proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid`

Note that there are a number of different types of UUID. The UUID generated in this example can be recognised by the fact that the 3rd chunk starts with a '4' which IIRC is UUID for 'this is a random 128bit number encoded as UUID'. There's also for instance UUIDs based on URLs which might be a better choice if you want a deterministic way to map the ID tokens to your 'products'.